# Python3.x Pandas .ewm() .std() returns all NaN with half-life

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using the examples from the [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/window.html#window-exponentially-weighted) I tried implementing an exponential moving window standard deviation, but the code returns all NaN unexpectedly:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'B': [0, 1, 2, np.nan, 4],
    'T': pd.DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-01', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-10', '2020-01-15', '2020-01-17'])
})

df.ewm(halflife='4 days', times='T').std()
```

Returns:

```
    B
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
```

I would expect the first value to be NaN, the rest not. (Or am I mistaken here?)

---

However, when I run their .mean() function on the ewm, I get the correct output:

```py
df.ewm(halflife='4 days', times='T').mean()
```

Returns:

```
    B
0   0.000000
1   0.585786
2   1.523889
3   1.523889
4   3.233686
```

I also get some output when using span instead of half-life:

```py
df.ewm(span=2).std()
```

Returns:

```
    B
0   NaN
1   0.707107
2   0.919866
3   0.919866
4   1.720513
```

---

Am I using the API incorrectly / did I misunderstand some concept here, or is this a bug?

Comment: What is the version? Because in pandas 1.3.0 `df.ewm(halflife='4 days', times='T').std()` produces `B` -> `[nan, 0.7071067811865476, 0.9636241116594315, 0.9636241116594315, 1.810463415200036]`

Comment: Pandas 1.2.4 - Thanks a lot, I didn't realize that this was implemented/fixed in 1.3!

Comment: I updated to 1.3 and can confirm that it works. What shall I do with this SO question?

Comment: I feel that it's a generally helpful question for anyone else having similar issues. Perhaps someone can also determine _why_ it doesn't work in 1.2.4.